# How can I calculate a value based on the value of rows in a MySQL update trigger?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a table with three rows. When a value in either of the first two rows is updated, I want to trigger an update to a value in row3.

This is roughly the logic I'm hoping to implement (pseudocode):

```
On update 
if (row1.value-row2val.value) > 0 then 
update row3 value =  (row1.value-row2.value) else 
/* don't update row3 */
```

How might I build this into a SQL trigger or, failing that, build equivalent logic into the PHP code that updates the first two rows?

Comment: In MySQL, the word "row" usually means "a collection of values." You cannot subtract a collection of values. Are you trying to compare values in a row?

Comment: I mean for row here any row E.g : row1 = Lastposts ; row2 = newposts

Comment: You need to be a LOT more verbose. What does row1 look like? What does row2 look like? What does "row1-row2" mean? What do you want row3 to look like? This question has been viewed 12 times now and nobody has commented. That tends to mean that they don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Reformatted to code and text to be clearer and removed extraneous text at end of question.

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear - currently it reads as though you have a table with only three rows, you're updating the first two via your PHP code and wish to automatically update the third. I've edited your question to reflect this, but if that's NOT your intent here then please revise it to reflect what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Row1 mean total posts and Row2 mean excluded posts so when i set 
cron job it should update Row1 and Row2 foreach user and want it 
on update to fill row3 mean Finalposts i don't want to use php for this